# Strange message when opening a file

Tags: nsopenpanel

opening a file witch NSOpenPanel openPanel I get strange warnings about 5 or 6 files that do not exist.
As an example:
(xxxx is the name of a teacher at my school in those days)

> 2020-05-19 19:30:45.113203+0200 USB_Stepper[10340:1206411] [default] Faild to get owner UUID for url: file:///Users/xxxx/Public error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Public” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/xxxx/Public, NSFilePath=/Users/xxxx/Public, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000e92580 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

The file in the warning cames from  computer 2 devices before my actual one about 8 years ago. Any try to find something on my machine gave no results.
Where can I look for it?